# Can you install a NserviceBus windows service from within a .Net application?

Tags: windows-services, nservicebus

Right now we install our NserviceBus using a .bat file that looks something like this:

NServiceBus.Host.exe /install /serviceName:"Cool Service" /displayName:"Cool service Name" /description:"Cool Servcie Desc" /username:"Skroob" /password:"1234" NServiceBus.Production 
 pause

I was wondering if it is possible to install the service using a .Net application. I have looked at TopShelf and the ServiceController namespace, but I can not seem to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: How about using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start?